# Java exception handling with instantiate Exception superclass and IOException subclass

Tags: java, oop, exception, inheritance, compiler-errors

First I create a class called OrderHandler.java. I declared an instance of superclass Exception and an instance of subclass IOException in a main method.

Now the question is to show a compilation error when you try catching the superclass exception type before the subclass exception type. What should I do? Need I create some methods to show the path? Or do I need to instantiate the OrderHandler as well?
Thanks

```
import java.io.IOException;

    public class OrderHandler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Exception A = new Exception();
        IOException B = new IOException();              
    }    
}
```

Comment: There aren't even any Exceptions thrown.

Comment: Yap, I think the question just want me to show it is impossible to catch superclass exception before the subclass exception type, no more specific requirements .

Comment: have you tried writing code like this: try {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        } and compiling it? Most current IDE's at least will already mark it as invalid code

Comment: I have to use the instance of exception class and IOException class to show the path.

Comment: which is exactly what I did in that example. Your code makes no sense. There are no exceptions thrown, so there is nothing to catch

Comment: The question to show the arrangement(order) of the catch blocks. The question allows to make some methods without code in OrderHandler in order to make exception throw.

Comment: again: have you checked the code snippet I've put in my comment?

Comment: Yep, I have checked, but shows an error.

Comment: exactly: and it's that error your question is about. it shows an error, because I try to catch Exception (super class) before IOException (subclass). This means that all IOExceptions will already be caught in the first block, leading to an unreachable catch block.

Comment: Thanks sir. But how can I use the instances of superclass and subclass in the code and show it is  an unreachable catch block?

Comment: The error already shows that. If you need more, put "throw new IOException("IOException test");" within the try block

Comment: "_But how can I use the instances of superclass and subclass in the code and show it is an unreachable catch block?_" – If Stultuske's comments don't already answer that question, then you need to clarify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're not catching any exceptions in your sample code.  I think you mean this:

```
try {
  // do some stuff
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // report a general exception
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // report an IO exception
}
```

This isn't going to do what you want it to do.  You need to catch more specific exceptions first, otherwise the IOException block will never execute.  The correct way to do this is:

```
try {
  // do some stuff
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // report an IO exception
} catch (Exception ex) {
  // report a general exception
}
```